# How to order list string by order priority in reactjs

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to order a list string first by number -> alphabet -> Japanese kanji
using javascript.

Here is an example of list :

```
["123servie", "4service", "4abc", "テンプレートを選択service"]
```

After reorder, the list should look like this :

```
["123service", "4abc", "4service", "テンプレートを選択service"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let  list = ["123servie", "4service", "4abc", "テンプレートを選択service"];
list.sort();
console.log(list)

//or

list.sort((a, b) =>{
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b < a) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sort(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
}
```

[More about localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)